# Checking for duplicate usernames in Database

Tags: servlets

I have this Servlet code, I am trying to check for duplicate usernames in the database but it does not seem to work out.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String confirmpassword = request.getParameter("confirm_password");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/account";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "school");

        Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from Users where username='" + username + "';");

        String duplicate;

        while (rs.next()) {
            duplicate = rs.getString(username);

            if (password.equals("confirmpassword") && duplicate != username) {
                statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO info values('" + username + "','" + password + "');");
                out.println("Registraion Successful!");
                out.println("Your Username: "+username);
                out.println("Your Password: "+password);

            }
            if (duplicate.equals(username)){
                out.println("Please choose a different username..:)");
            }
        }




    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistrationServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone types `'; TRUNCATE TABLE Users; --` in the your site's username box and…  oops!

Comment: "Does not seem to work out" doesn't tell us much.  What goes wrong?  Any specific exceptions, error messages, or places where the debugger shows the code doing something unexpected?

Comment: @Wyzard java.sql.SQLException: Column 'ankur' not found.

Comment: On what line does that exception occur?  The string "ankur" doesn't occur anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: @Wyzard I am trying to enter username ankur..and then it shows that..

Comment: But what line is throwing that exception?  It means you're constructing an SQL string wrong somewhere, using the `username` variable as if it were the name of a database column, but neither of the queries in this code does that.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the line `duplicate = rs.getString(username);`.  You meant to retrieve the value in the username column from the result set, but you're using the `username` *variable*, not the string `"username"`.  When you enter "ankur" as the username, that line is equivalent to `duplicate = rs.getString("ankur");`, and there's no column named `ankur` in the result set.

You have a bunch of other bugs as well:

- `rs.next()` will only return true if the query found an existing user record with the specified username.  That means you can only get to the successful registration code if there *is* a duplicate user.
- `password.equals("confirmpassword")` means that the user has to actually type the word "confirmpassword" in the password box or their registration will be rejected.  I think you meant `password.equals(confirmpassword)`.
- You're logging into your database as root and you have [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities.  A malicious user could do anything they want with your database, such as modifying or deleting your data.
- Why are you catching and ignoring `ClassNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 3):

```
Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from Users where username='" + username + "'");

String duplicate = null;

while(rs.next()){
duplicate = rs.getString(1);
}

if(duplicate == null){
// ur logic
}
else{
out.println("Please choose a different username..:)");
}
```